# Setting height of View in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-xml

I have a this layout in my application. The black color bar below the image is a `View` element. I want this bar height to fill the whole area below the image.

[image: Layout Image]

This is my layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/layoutNote"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/_10sdp"
        app:cardElevation="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="#C9E9FF"
        android:padding="@dimen/_5sdp"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgNote"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:visibility="gone"
                app:riv_corner_radius_top_left="@dimen/_10sdp"
                app:riv_corner_radius_top_right="@dimen/_10sdp"/>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <View
                    android:layout_width="3dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:minHeight="50dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="start"
                    android:id="@+id/colorBar"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:background="@color/grad_23"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_15ssp"
                android:padding="@dimen/_5sdp"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@id/colorBar"
                android:fontFamily="@font/manrope_bold"
                android:textColor="@color/lightGrey"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvWebLink"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tvTitle"
                android:fontFamily="@font/manrope_bold"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/_2sdp"
                android:paddingStart="@dimen/_5sdp"
                android:textColor="@color/ColorGray"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_12ssp"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:autoLink="web"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvDesc"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_11ssp"
                android:layout_below="@id/tvWebLink"
                android:paddingStart="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/_5sdp"
                android:paddingEnd="@dimen/_5sdp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/manrope_regular"
                android:textColor="@color/ColorText"/>

            <TextView
                 android:id="@+id/tvDateTime"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:textSize="@dimen/_9ssp"
                 android:paddingStart="@dimen/_10sdp"
                 android:paddingBottom="@dimen/_5sdp"
                 android:layout_below="@id/tvDesc"
                 android:fontFamily="@font/manrope_regular"
                 android:textColor="@color/ColorText"/>

            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

In the `View` tag, when I set the height to match parent, the whole view becomes invisible while running the application, so I'm using a `android:minHeight="50dp"`

```
              <View
                    android:layout_width="3dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:minHeight="50dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="start"
                    android:id="@+id/colorBar"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:background="@color/grad_23"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>
```

I tried using a `LinearLayout` with `layout_weight="1"`, which didn't work either. Any idea on how I could solve this?

Comment: The code should just work fine .... No issues with it... its not reproducible with the code you have given

Comment: But if the remove the minHeight, the whole view is just gone.

Comment: Nope its not possible ... either you must be adding something else to your code or removing something else from your code... the code that you mentioned is just fine

Comment: Why not change the layouts (Linear+Relative) to a ConstraintLayout? The code looks just fine, but a ConstraintLayout would give you a lot more of control and performance

Comment: I changed everything to ConstraintLayout now and I have the same issue, the view is not showing if I don't give it a minHeight